# How to use Qt qss selectors

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I can't get the qss selectors as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) to work.

This is my .qss:

```
QHBoxLayout QLabel {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

This has no effect on my QLabel

[image].

However this will:

```
QLabel {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

As seen here

[image].

Bonus edit:

this seems to work differently yet

[image].

Can anybody explain what is going on?

Comment: First case `QHBoxLayout QLabel` won't work cause QHBoxLayout is not a parent of a QLabel, but QDockWidget is. What are you trying to achieve? If you need to apply the stylesheet only to the children of a QDockWidget you need to use `QDockWidget QLabel`

Comment: Thanks @lena. I thought the QHBoxLayout was a UI element, apparently this is not the case.